# Rectangle with curved sides

Tags: css, css-shapes

How can I achieve this by simple DIV with css?

HTML:

```
<div class="curv">
    <div class="holder"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.curv{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.curv:before{
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}
.holder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

What I am getting now is:
https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/fnL3wzrn/

I want to look the corners to be sharp edges and not smooth. So it will look like this: [image]

Comment: @JoshCrozier Updated the question. Hope this describes better than before. If you think is good can you up-vote please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check updated code

```css
.curv{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.curv:before{
    background: #333;
    height: 200px;
    left: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    top: 10px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 0 0;
}
.holder{
     height: 200px;
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="curv">
    <div class="holder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the above css. I want the corners to be sharper. Not rounded. Only upper side need to be curved.

Comment: you can see now. I had update just

Comment: Thanks kumar , it's what I was looking for.