# Div with curved in sides

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I'm looking to create the below unique shape as a text container, but not sure if it's possible with a div. I've tried a few border-radius and positioning CSS hacks, and clearly none have worked. I want to be able to have a colored border, a background-image to fill it, and text to be able to go inside as a title. How might I go about creating this shape? Is CSS even the way to go? Or is SVG a better bet? Help?

[image: shape]

I've already seen these SO posts that are similar, but not quite what I'm looking for:

[Rectangle with curved sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860810/rectangle-with-curved-sides) | 
[How to create div with curve in css and html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191208/how-to-create-div-with-curve-in-css-and-html5)

Comment: Your picture does not link to anywhere :(

Comment: I didn't intend for it to link, but to display the type of shape I wanted to create.

Comment: This question is overly broad! You're basically asking us to write the code for you. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I truly did not intend that at all.  What I meant (but failed to articulate) is the direction I might take to create this shape--as it is fairly complicated.

Comment: take a look at my answer for a pure css way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an SVG as your outer shape mask and put whatever you want in that mask. In this case, you can put a repeating circle BG inside the shape and apply the SVG as it's mask.

You can find full tutorials online for SVG masking by simply googling SVG Masking - or you can check this one out at: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/mask.html

Side note: To avoid downvotes in the future, please include examples of what you have tried so that we have something to work with in helping you solve your programming concern.

Comment: Thank you to both. I will take a look at this particular tutorial, and see what I can't come up with.

Thank you as well for your SO advice. This place tends to be brutal.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use images as a border, but the shape you are trying to make would be difficult doing this. To use an image border you have to have a shape which is more square.

However you could use an svg as a background image and make it 100% of the div container.

```
#div
{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../../../images/test.svg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

You may not been the background-size. Try with and without to see the difference. Sometimes it helps with svgs, sometimes not.

If you need to constrain the size you have two options. Make this div a specific size or, make a fixed width div and put this div inside.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this for you with pure CSS, however, in production you'd need to adjust the z-index so the :before and :after pseudo elements don't block other content.

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/Cruiser/pen/KgwOxv

Basically, we use some cool background tricks and the :before and :after with white borders and absolute positioning to get the shape to look like your image.

```
.bendy:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  background-color:white;
  width:53%;
  height:50%;
  top:-175px;
  left:436px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:white;
  border-bottom-color:blue;
  border-bottom-width:10px;
  border-radius: 40%;
}
```

The background is modified from: http://bennettfeely.com/gradients/, a great site for cool background tricks with CSS. Here's the gist--

```
background:
radial-gradient(
    magenta,
    magenta 40%,
    transparent 40%,
    transparent 100%
), floralwhite;

background-size:
    4em 4em;

background-blend-mode: multiply;
background-position:
    0 0,
    -33% -33%,
    -200% -200%;
 }
```